# FireStore Tasks.whenAllComplete with Coroutines

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I want to implement this code synchronously
but `job.join`, `deferred.await`, and firebase `await`, not working.
Does anyone know a solution?

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {

        val job = launch {

            Tasks.whenAllComplete(tasks)
                .addOnCompleteListener {

                    Log.d("user-get", "on-0-> addOnComplete")

                    tasks.forEach { task ->

                        val snapshot = task.result

                        Log.d("user-get", "on->"+ task.toString())

                        snapshot.documents.forEach {
                            docs.add(it)
                        }

                    }

                }
        }

        job.join()

        Log.d("user-get", "job-end")
}
```

Log order:

```
D/user-get: job-end

D/user-get: on-0-> addOnComplete

D/user-get: on->com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw@5c0519d
```

`deferred` and `await`, and `Task.whenAllComplete(tasks).addOnCompleteListener { ~~~ }.await` 
are also same log result.

really appreciate Alex! the below is the code that I mentioned at comment

```
override suspend fun checkNickName(nickName: String): Results<Int> {


    lateinit var result : Results<Int>

    fireStore.collection("database")
        .document("user")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { document ->
            if (document.isSuccessful) {

                val list = document.result.data?.get("nickNameList") as List<String>

                if (list.contains(nickName))
                    result = Results.Exist(1)
                else
                    result = Results.No(0)

                //document.getResult().get("nickNameList")
            }
            else {

            }
        }.await()

    return result
}
```

**Is it proper way to use both firebase and coroutine?**
it was executed as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented in an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630036/firestore-geoquery-with-coroutines) of yours, there is no need to launch a coroutine when you attach a listener. It's one, or the other. When you call [`Tasks#whenAllComplete(Task...<?> tasks`)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllComplete(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)), the type of object that is returned is `Task<List<Task<?>>`. This means that all the heavy work is done behind the scenes, in a different thread. So there is nothing that can block the main thread. When you attach a listener, it means that you'll wait until the operation is complete, or fails with an exception. So you either get the request out of the coroutine or, as @Sergio mentioned in his answer, remove the listener and call [await()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/await.html). Please also note that this function is a suspend function and not a blocking function.

Now, since this operation can raise an exception, is recommended to add the following lines of code inside a method, perhaps in a repository class, and use a try-catch together with [Kotlin flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html):

```
fun getDocs() = flow {
    try {
        val tasks = Tasks.whenAllComplete(tasks).await()
        tasks.forEach { task ->
            val snapshot = task.result
            snapshot.documents.forEach {
                docs.add(it)
            }
        }
        emit(docs)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(e)
    }
}
```

And inside a ViewModel class launch a coroutine and collect the result:

```
fun getDocs() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repo.getDocs().collect { docs ->
        //Do what you need to do with the documents
    }
}
```

So most likely you might consider converting the list of [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) objects into a list of custom objects of yours. That being said, an even simpler solution, would be not to iterate but to call [QuerySnapshot#toObjects(Class clazz)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#toObjects(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)):

```
val tasks = Tasks.whenAllComplete(tasks).await()
val docs = tasks.toObjects(YourModelClass::class.java)
```

I have written an article called:

- [How to make a clean architecture Android app, using MVVM, Firestore, and Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8)

Where I explain step by step how you can achieve that. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp). And here is [a line of code](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp/blob/bfa1d2735cabaf5abae219f74952b32e914d8065/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firestorecleanarchitecture/data/repository/BooksRepositoryImpl.kt#L22) where I do the the conversion.

Comment: Really thanks Alex, I should learn the way which firebase method run and coroutine itself. by the way, I have created many firebase functions with 'suspend' keyword because of using 'await' to implement functions synchronously. is that right way? I uploaded the code on the question please check :)

Comment: Yep, at a first glance, it looks good to me.

Comment: So, can I help you with other information?

Comment: thanks again Alex! ur explanation is very helpful to me :) have a nice weekend

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to do is to not use `addOnCompleteListener` and use `await()` function on the `Task` object instead:

```
coroutineScope.launch {

    val tasks = Tasks.whenAllComplete(tasks).await() // Awaits the completion of the task without blocking a thread.
    
    tasks.forEach { task ->

        val snapshot = task.result

        Log.d("user-get", "on->"+ task.toString())

        snapshot.documents.forEach {
            docs.add(it)
        }
    }

    Log.d("user-get", "job-end")

}
```