# firestore, coroutine and flow

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

firebase method is working on worker thread automatically. but I have used coroutine and callbackflow to implement firebase listener code synchronously or get return from the listener.
below is my code that I explained

**coroutine await with firebase for one shot**

```
override suspend fun checkNickName(nickName: String): Results<Int> {


    lateinit var result : Results<Int>

    fireStore.collection("database")
        .document("user")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { document ->


            if (document.isSuccessful) {

                val list = document.result.data?.get("nickNameList") as List<String>

                if (list.contains(nickName))
                    result = Results.Exist(1)
                else
                    result = Results.No(0)

                //document.getResult().get("nickNameList")
            }
            else {

            }
        }.await()

    return result
}
```

**callbackflow with firebase listener**

```
override fun getOwnUser(): Flow<UserEntity> = callbackFlow{

    val document = fireStore.collection("database/user/userList/")
        .document("test!!!!!")

    val subscription = document.addSnapshotListener { snapshot,_ ->

        if (snapshot!!.exists()) {

            val ownUser = snapshot.toObject<UserEntity>()

            if (ownUser != null) {
                trySend(ownUser)
            }
        }
    }

    awaitClose { subscription.remove() }

}
```

so I really wonder these way is good or bad practice and its reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not combine `addOnCompleteListener` with coroutines `await()`. There is no guarantee that the listener gets called before or after `await()`, so it is possible the code in the listener won't be called until after the whole suspend function returns. Also, one of the major reasons to use coroutines in the first place is to avoid using callbacks. So your first function should look like:

```
override suspend fun checkNickName(nickName: String): Results<Int> {
    try {
        val userList = fireStore.collection("database")
            .document("user")
            .get()
            .await()
            .get("nickNameList") as List<String>

        return if (userList.contains(nickName)) Results.Exist(1) else Results.No(0)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // return a failure result here
    }
}
```

Your use of `callbackFlow` looks fine, except you should add a `buffer()` call to the flow you're returning so you can specify how to handle backpressure. However, it's possible you will want to handle that downstream instead.

```
override fun getOwnUser(): Flow<UserEntity> = callbackFlow {
    //...
}.buffer(/* Customize backpressure behavior here */)
```

Comment: it also use implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.1"??

Comment: I think so. There may be a few different ways to pull in the ktx extensions for Firestore. Often with Google libraries, you can just add `-ktx` to the artifact name to find the version with the the extensions.